# use TextBox TextChanged Event to filter the input

Tags: c#, wpf

So I created a `TextBox` called "`wa_txt`", which should contain a number '`wa`' between `wa_min` and `wa_max` (let's say 10 and 100 for an example)

If the text inside the `TextBox` is invalid a `MessageBox` should appear warning the user and resetting the value to the old value.

This is inside my `wa_txt_Texchanged` event:

```
int wa = 0;
int wa_max = 100;
int wa_min = 10;
Int32.TryParse(wa_txt.Text, out wa);

if (wa == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("not a number", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    wa_txt.Text = wa_old.ToString();
    return;
}
if (wa > wa_max)
{
    MessageBox.Show("number too big", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    wa_txt.Text = wa_old.ToString();
    return;
}
if (wa < wa_min)
{
    MessageBox.Show("number too small", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    wa_txt.Text = wa_old.ToString();
    return;
}
wa_old = wa;
```

My Problem is that as soon as i am starting to type 100 and type the 1, the `MessageBox` shows up telling me my number is too small and resets it back to the last valid number.

Any way i can make the check after I am finished typing ?

edit: I'd like the event to fire also when leaving the `TextBox` without pressing a button, which didn't work with a keydown event as far as I tried.

Comment: Try looking at the `LostFocus` event on the `UIElement` -- see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, Question: Are you using the MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty much logical that when you're entering a number in `wa_txt` it will always state that number is invalid and resets back to the last valid number. Explanation:

```
if (wa < wa_min)
{
    MessageBox.Show("number too small", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    wa_txt.Text = wa_old.ToString();
    return;
}
```

Obviously, this is the `if` block that is giving you the problem. Your minimum number is `wa_min = 10;`. All numbers that you will start entering are between 0 and 9. They are all less than 10. In this case, that `if` statement is always true. As if you're saying:

```
if (true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("number too small", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    wa_txt.Text = wa_old.ToString();
    return;
}
```

What I suggest is copying your `TextChanged` logic to [`LostFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void SoTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Your logic.
}
```

This will run the logic you're doing when the `TextBox` loses focus. This event will fire whenever the `TextBox` loses focus being by a button press or mouse click. Also, you won't face the problem when your minimum number is bigger than 9. Otherwise, I suggest you work with some kind of timers to give the user a bit of time to enter the whole number.

Comment: @Azzarrel I am glad that I've been able to help. Since you're new to SO, always keep in mind to accept the answer that best suits you regarding your questions.